# Static blocks on home page

Tags: magento2

I've been using Magento 1 a while and wanted to see what Magento 2 was like.

I installed it via cpanel with the demo content.

The home page has a slider and other blocks of images / products.

I go to the home page in the content> pages section and see there is nothing on the page.

I check the static blocks and see there is a home page static block.. but I have to ask.

1) Why use a static block for this when you could have just put in on the page
2) How is the static block being called / pulled to the home page ?

When i use static blocks in Magento 1 I use code like

```
{{block id="block_name"}}
```

to call the content.

Comment: Hi Dave, sorry to hear M2 is a challenge. It's indeed a whole other beast than M1 but from experience, I can tell you that it's worth diving into.

To get the best response on this forum I would like advise you to refactor your question a bit. Keep the question objective. M2 is hard but it's just a fact of life.
1 question per post: to keep the goal of the question clear.
Describe exactly what you run into. try to be exact in what you want to accomplish

Comment: Thanks... Do you mean you'd like me to edit this question now or just going forward ?

Comment: If you can please edit the question now so we can work towards getting it reopened

Comment: Changed it to be more directed to the static block part.

Answer (score 1):

> Is 2 made more complex on purpose?

As someone currently migrating to Magento 2, this is a question I find myself asking every day...

> how is the static block appearing on the page?

I can't remember off the top of my head, but if you search online you'll find the answer - this was one of the first things I changed. Layout/design editing is heavily XML-based in Magento 2, so it'll likely be changed in a config file.

> I made a new page with just some demo text to see how it looked and there was no menu / search bar / login area on the page.. I couldn't see how to add it either

This is just the default value (`Empty`) for the "Layout" option in the page "Design" tab - change to `1 column` (or whichever value you'd like), refresh/flush your cache, and check again.

It's a steep learning curve, but things do begin to slowly make sense. Good luck!

Comment: thanks. it was the cache flush that was the issue. Thanks.